# parsing numbers from a sentence

Tags: python, regex

I have a sentence that looks like this:

```
word word - word -word- $1.2 - $2,222 $5 '
```

I need to get all the numbers, but the dash between the one and the two is actually considered a number in this case.  So I want to get an array that looks like:  `[ $1.2 |  - |  $2,222 |  $5]`

The dollar signs are not a problem

I'm trying this:

```
(\s+-(?![a-zA-Z]*5)|[\$\d\.,]+\s
```

The idea is that I want either a dash with no letters to the right of it or a number complex (bunch of numbers, dots and commas), and any spaces around that.

I'm currently getting this:

```
 -  - $1.2  $2,222  $5
```

... all the dashes I don't want and none of the dashes I do want.

Comment: Sorry - meant "the dash between the numbers to the right"

Comment: are the last four words always numbers/amounts?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  There's always more text both before and after.  DYZs answer did solve it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex works for your example:

```
r = r'(?:\s+-\s+(?![a-zA-Z]))|[\$\d\.,]+'
re.findall(r, s)
#['$1.2', ' - ', '$2,222', '$5']
```

Comment: Thank you.  It does, but I don't understand it.  Is that a non-capturing group around the dash?

Comment: Also, when I tried it on a more real world example (""doubtful accounts (in thousands):      - newline-allowance as of beginning of year   $2,038    - $2,143    $3,096"), it has problems with the commas.

Comment: Yes, it is a non-capturing group with a negative lookahead .

Comment: @paszoon please post such "real world examples" in your question to avoid the [x-y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). If you don't explicitly mention all edge cases, you can't expect answers to account for them.

Comment: I ran the code on your example and got `['$2,038', ' - ', '$2,143', '$3,096']`. What is the problem with commas that you experience?

Comment: getting:     ,038     -  ,143 ,096

Comment: As long as I run the code literally on the example that you provided in the second comment, I am getting the right answer.

Comment: Absolutely.  My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do this in regex, but here is how I did it (probably more straightforward than regex):

```py
myList = []
numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "-", "$", ".", ","]
myString = "word word - word -word- $1.2 - $2,222 $5 '"
for word in myString.split(" "):
    isNumber = True
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in numbers:
            isNumber = False
    if isNumber:
        myList.append(word)
print(myList)
```

I hope this helps, even if it isn't exactly what you wanted. If you want an explanation, just leave a comment, and I'd be happy to explain.